# MVC4 Drop-down dynamic SelectList. what went wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc4 and trying to generate dropdownlist dynamically. I want to create a list for next 10 years. Where my understanding gone wrong?

Model

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DropDownList.Models;

namespace DropDownList.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ddlist DropList = new ddlist();
            var years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10);
            var select = new SelectList(years.Select(y => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = y.ToString(),
                Value = y.ToString()
            }));
            DropList.CountryList = select.ToList(); 
            return View(DropList);
        }

    }
}
```

----------Controller-----

```
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DropDownList.Models
{
    public class ddlist
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Country")]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

-------------View-----------------

```
@model DropDownList.Models.ddlist 
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(
model => model.CountryCode, 
Model.CountryList, "select"
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryCode
```

---

Following are the output. what i am expecting to see years like 2014, 2015..

> select
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem

Comment: Are you going to explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely to return a `SelectList`

1) Change the model to:

```
public class ddlist
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Country")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    public SelectList CountryList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

2) And then return the list as `SelectList` to the model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DropList ddlist = new ddlist();
    var years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10);
    var select = new SelectList(years.Select(y => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = y.ToString(),
        Value = y.ToString()
    }));

    DropList.CountryList = select; //Removing the ToList and Using the SelectList

    return View(DropList);
}
```

Comment: It thrown an error. Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: Did you cast to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>? Looks like you are missing the generic T parameter.

Comment: i tried the above it return the same System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem, System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItemm, System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem

Comment: Just change to the method 2 as I explained above. I did the first way here and it works.

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(
model => model.CountryCode,
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.CountryList, "select")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryCode). no difference still the same

Comment: Read the entire awnsear and you will rock. Just look Above!